# how to import multiple folders containing images ,in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

I want to select just folders instead of selecting each images individually.
for example I have 8 folders and each of then including 72 dicom images. my purpose is to just select 8 folders and  save each folder images in one row of array. I have written this code but it only read multiple images in one folder. please help me to solve my problem.

```
function cell=readfromfile()
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.*', 'Pick folder','Multiselect','on');
img_dir =pathname;
filename(1);
    N =length(filename);
strfile =filename{1};
img = dicomread(fullfile(img_dir, strfile));
siz_img = size(img);
% create result matrix:
% load all the remaining images and put them in the matrix
for ii=2:N
    strfile =filename{ii};
    I{ii}=dicomread( fullfile(pathname, filename{ii}) );
end
```

Comment: There is no built in command to do this. There are, however, a few tools on the MathWorks File Exchange, like [`uipickfiles`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/02/19/file-and-folder-selection-gui/) and [`uigetfile_n_dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32555-uigetfile-n-dir---select-multiple-files-and-directories). The latter is simply a wrapper for the Java [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

Answer (score 0):

Neither uigetfile or uigetdir allow you to select multiple folders, so I would probably just use uigetdir to get the path of the selected folder. If you know you have 8 folders you can just call this in a loop 8 times (making sure not to overwrite you data). If you don't know how many folders you have you may need to so something cunning, but I haven't really thought about it.

I would then use [dir](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html?searchHighlight=dir) to get a list of the files in your folders. You may need to use something like `dir('*.png');` if you have any subfolders or other files you don't want to read in the folder.

Your reading of the images looks fine from there.

Comment: as you said i don't know about number of my folders. in other words i want to import that folders from DVD to my program and then do some processing on that images.

Comment: If the folders are all in the same place you could probably use dir on the their location to get all the folder names. You may need to use isdir(name) or the listing from dir to only select the folders if there is any files outside the folders.